# copy like Tables and extended Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a table, Table_1

```
 name      id
 ABC       A001
 BCD       A002
 CDE       A003
```

so if i create Table_2 with same attributes as Table_1
i tried copying all rows of Table_1 to Table_2 with below query, but not sure

```
Insert into Table_2 values (Select * from Table_1)
```

and also if i extent Table_1 with one additional column and create a third, Table_3, is it possible to copy Table_1 records to Table_3
(say Table_1 has (name, id) & Table_3 (name, id, passwd))

(running on MS Sql server 2005)

Comment: Presuming Table_2 doesn't exist the quick and dirty way is `SELECT * INTO Table_2 FROM Table_1` see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029(v=sql.90).aspx. For Table_3 you would specify your columns like `INSERT INTO Table_3 (name, id) SELECT name, id FROM Table_1`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of asking have you tried doing it? This is not a case of a test that's hard to set up.

Comment: answer of the year hehe, if newbies at one trade are treated like this then i am glad to take ur answer bro...